# Função php que chama retorno de outra função

Tags: php, doctrine

Olá, sou novo no **PHP OO** e no **Doctrine**. Eu gostaria de retornar o valor de uma função dentro de outra função. É possível? Ambas estão dentro de uma mesma classe.

**Função que receberá o resultado:**

```
public function salvar(Request $request, EM $em)
{
    $FinContaspagar = new FinContaspagar(
        $_SESSION["grupo"],
        $_SESSION["estabelecimento"],
        $request->get('terceiro'),
        /****************RESULTADO DA FUNÇÃO AQUI**********/,
        $request->get('dtemissao'),
        $request->get("dtvencimento")
    );

    $em->persist($FinContaspagar);
    $em->flush();

    return redirect('contas')->with('success_message', 'Cadastrado com sucesso');
}
```

**Função que gera o valor:**

```
public function insereCodigo(em $em){

    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT COALESCE(MAX(u.codigo+1),1) as Codigo
                                 FROM ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar u 
                                WHERE u.grupo = :sessionGrupo
                                  AND u.estabelecimento = :sessionEstabelecimento');
    $query->setParameter('sessionGrupo',$_SESSION["grupo"])
        ->setParameter('sessionEstabelecimento',$_SESSION["estabelecimento"]);
    $codigo = $query->getResult();

    return $codigo[0]["Codigo"];
}
```

Caso não seja possível, ou não seja recomendado realizar desta maneira, como posso proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso que para um melhor entendimento seria melhor receber esse valor antes da chamada da função:

```
$retorno = $this->insereCodigo($em);
```

ou dessa forma, porém não sei se funciona:

```
 $FinContaspagar = new FinContaspagar(
    $_SESSION["grupo"],
    $_SESSION["estabelecimento"],
    $request->get('terceiro'),
    $this->insereCodigo($em),
    $request->get('dtemissao'),
    $request->get("dtvencimento")
);
```

Comment: Obrigado @Evandro! A primeira solução funcionou! Eu estava fazendo exatamente igual a segunda forma, realmente não da certo. Valeu!